# User and password database login

Tags: database, security, authentication, passwords, timeline

I have a project in mind, but i thinking of the part when a user can log in. I am going to do a login & register window frame in javaFX, and now comes the tricky part?

Im not sure how to to the login correct, the username is supposed to save in a database. And the password to be secure i need to use a crypt algorithm(like blowfish, or md5hash?) but im not sure where to save that, in a array or how you do it. 
WOuld really appriciate if someone could give me some good advices:D

Comment: This question on security.se may be helpful to you. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords . You just store the hashed password in the same database as the username. That's fine... as long as it is securely hashed/salted. It's common to base64 encode the hashed value and store THAT in your table.

Comment: Definitely see @Gray's link to "How to securely hash passwords?", which boils down to "Use BCrypt, SCrypt, or PBKDF2" with as large a work factor/iteration count as you can afford to spend the processing time on during peak times and a random 8-16 byte salt.  Store the salt (in the clear), work factor/iteration count (in the clear, so you can easily increase it later as users log in), a version (of the password hashing technique - start at, say, 1 :) ), and the hash itself in binary, or encoded in Base64, or in hex in the database or a text file or whatever your server side data store is.